# Skipping specific lines and storing variables specific variables in C

Tags: c, fgets, lines, fgetc

This is a simple question but I just can't seem to figure it out. I need a little help. I have a file called programFile that looks like this:

```
start mul val1
<--tab-->ldb #2
<--tab-->addr A B
<--tab-->float
loop lda #1
<--tab-->sta val2
<--tab-->j loop
val1 word 12
val2 word 0
```

I want to take only the lines that do not start with the tab and do something with them (for now I just want to print the first word in that line), so only the lines `start mul val1`, `loop lda #1`, `val1 word 12` and `val2 word 0`. The output should be:

```
start
loop
val1
val2
```

Eventually, I also want to take the lines that start with the tab and do something different with them, but this is my poor attempt at solving it:

```
while(ch = fgetc(programFile) != EOF){
    if(ch == '\t'){
        while(ch != '\n'){
            ch = fgetc(programFile);
        }
    }else{
        fscanf(programFile, "%s", symbol);
        printf("%s\n", symbol);
    }
}
```

And this is my output:

```
tart
ldb
addr
float
loop
sta
j
val1
val2
```

Comment: To read file _lines_, better to use `fgets()` than `fgetc/fscanf()`

Comment: I highly recommend the use of scripting languages like python or ruby script for preprocessing a file. The i/o libraries of scripting languages tend to have a lot less footguns to be aware of and even large files don't usually take more than a second to process. Still, this question is asked very well. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: `fscanf(programFile, "%s", symbol);` --> `ungetc(ch, programFile); fscanf(programFile, "%s", symbol);` Your input starts with a space rather than a tab. If you treat spaces like tabs, `if(ch == '\t'){` --> `if(isspace(ch)){`

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger and step one instruction at a time to see what you program actually does. But mixing `fgets` or `fgetc` and `scanf` is always a wrong idea and leads to problem. The correct way here *as input is line oriented* is to use `fgets` to read a line, test the first char of the line and use `sscanf` to decode the line

Comment: `while (fgets (line, sizeof line, fp)) { if (*line == '\t') continue; ...do something with line...}` will skip all lines beginning with a `tab` (don't forget the trailing `'\n'`)

Comment: What I would do: first, I would make a function that lets you choose the line you're going to work on. Dependening on what the first characters are, you would do something. To evaluate what the first characters are, I would fill a string of these characters and make a call to `strcmp` to evaluate if they are equal to <--tab--> or if they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comment, while there is nothing wrong with using *character-oriented* input functions (e.g. `fgetc`, `getc`), when needing to handle **"lines"** of data, you are far better served to use the *line-oriented* input functions provided by the C-library (`fgets`) or POSIX (`getline`) and then parsing the needed information from each line.

Why? Basically, convenience and efficiency. Line-oriented input functions provide a *buffered* read (reading multiple-characters each time) and for large input files can really help with file I/O. Next, regardless of the contents, you will read the whole line (provided there is sufficient storage for line when using `fgets` -- otherwise you will read multiple chunks until the complete line is read; `getline` will automatically allocate (and reallocate) sufficient storage to hold each line).

You then have the tools like `sscanf`, `strtok`, `strsep`, `strstr`, `strchr`, etc.. that you can parse whatever you need from the stored line. (you can also *always* use simple *pointer arithmetic* to parse any line with a pointer, or pair of pointers, "*walking the string*" and comparing each character as you go) In-memory operations on each character in a stored string are orders of magnitude faster than performing the same operation while doing file I/O on each at the same time.

When you are concerned about the beginning character of each line, you only need compare `line[0]` (or simply `*line`) against whatever character you are looking for.

The following is a simple example that reads from the input filename given as the first argument (or from `stdin`, by default if no filename is given) and then tests the beginning character of each line. If the line begins with a `tab`, it simply outputs the line preceded by a `tab` (after having skipped the `tab` from the file by outputting `line + 1`) followed by `-- begins with tab` (you can handle those lines however you like, or skip them entirely), otherwise it will output the line itself followed by `-- no tab`. The handling of the differing prefixed lines is completely up to you. You can build an array of pointers holding each different type of line, or use a struct containing the commands and tabbed content in pointer arrays to preserve the line associations (which commands go with which tabbed lines), if required.

The only other note on *line-oriented* input functions is that they read *up to and including* the trailing `'\n'`. You generally do not want to store strings with `newlines` dangling off the ends, so you will want to trim the `newlines` by overwriting the trailing `'\n'` with the *nul-terminating character*. The example does this by getting the length of each line with `strlen` and then overwriting the `newline` with `0` (which is equivalent to the character `'\0'`). I don't like to type...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 64

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char line[MAX] = "";
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (line, MAX, fp))   /* read each line in file  */
    {
        size_t len = strlen (line); /* get the length */

        if (line[len - 1] == '\n')  /* check for trailing '\n' */
            line[--len] = 0;        /* overwrite with nul-byte */

        if (*line == '\t') {        /* if first char is '\t'   */
            printf ("\t%s - begins with tab\n", line + 1);
            continue;
        }

        printf ("%s - no tab\n", line);     /* line has no tab */
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/tabfile.txt
start mul val1
        ldb #2
        addr A B
        float
loop lda #1
        sta val2
        j loop
val1 word 12
val2 word 0
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/filehandletab <dat/tabfile.txt
start mul val1 - no tab
        ldb #2 - begins with tab
        addr A B - begins with tab
        float - begins with tab
loop lda #1 - no tab
        sta val2 - begins with tab
        j loop - begins with tab
val1 word 12 - no tab
val2 word 0 - no tab
```

As pointed out in the comments, if your intent was to parse the first word from the lines not beginning with a `tab`, then you can simply use `strchr` to locate the first `space`, temporarily terminate line at the `space` make use of the command, and then restore the `space` so the string can be further parsed a second time, if required, e.g.

```
while (fgets (line, MAX, fp)) 
{
    char *p = NULL;
    size_t len = strlen (line);
    ...
    if (*line == '\t') {        /* if first char is '\t'   */
        printf ("\t%s - begins with tab\n", line + 1);
        continue;
    }

    if ((p = strchr (line, ' '))) {      /* find first ' ' */
        *p = 0;                          /* terminate at p */
        printf ("%s - no tab\n", line);  /* output line    */
        *p = ' ';                        /* restore ' '    */
    }
    else
        printf ("%s - no tab\n", line);    /* s has no tab */
}
```

Or, writing the same termination of line, removing the `if...else...` and the duplicate `printf`, you could do the following in a bit more compact, but arguably less readable, code (completely up to you):

```
    if ((p = strchr (line, ' ')))        /* find first ' ' */
        *p = 0;                          /* terminate at p */

    printf ("%s - no tab\n", line);      /* s has no tab */

    if (p)                               /* if terminated  */
        *p = ' ';                        /* restore ' '    */
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/filehandletab <dat/tabfile.txt
start - no tab
        ldb #2 - begins with tab
        addr A B - begins with tab
        float - begins with tab
loop - no tab
        sta val2 - begins with tab
        j loop - begins with tab
val1 - no tab
val2 - no tab
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: `... Basically, convenience and efficiency. Line-oriented input functions provide a buffered read ...` That is true, but getc() and fgetc() read from **exactly** the same buffer, thus there is no efficiency gain in using line-oriented input. Actually, line-oriented input is  (marginally) *slower*, because it forces you to make *at least* one extra pass over the same buffer.

Comment: The problem with `getc` is there is no guarantee how it is implemented, it may be a macro that evaluates the input stream more than once. The I/O penalty for a character-oriented read can be significant over it's line-oriented counterpart. Yes conditions may very whether reading from SSD or Platter drives (or tape), but you can easily prove this to yourself by timing the reads of a large text file (10-100M). I've seen order of magnitude differences in the tests I've run. I don't dispute that the FILE* stream is buffered, but the read times are still significantly different.

Comment: Hey @DavidC.Rankin, thanks for your help. I tried using the first approach you mentioned because that output would be better for my use, but when I tested it, my output came out to be `start mul  - no tab\n
 - no tab\n
 - begins with tab\n
 - begins with tab\n
 - no tab\n
 - begins with tab\n
loop lda # - no tab\n
 - no tab\n
 - begins with tab\n
 - no tab\n
 - begins with tab\n
val1 word  - no tab\n
 - no tab\n
val2 word  - no tab\n
0 - no tab` I tried debugging, and it seems len is always 10, for the lines w/out tabs and for the lines w/ tab, len is something different

Comment: If I understand you are getting a literal `start mul - no tab\n - no tab\n` that tells me you have **blank lines that begin with a** `tab`. Simple to handle, just add a second check to see if the following character is a `newline`, e.g. `if (*line == '\t') { if (line[1] == '\n') continue; ... }`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In all the implementations I've seen since 1985, getc() was implemented as a macro. But I agree: there is no guarantee. And the undelying FS (SSD, etc) is not relevant here: the read()s still go in block-sized chunks, typically 512 byes.

Comment: Do you have a source link for the `512` size? It appears to derive from `#define _G_BUFSIZ 8192` see [**sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/_G_config.h**](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/_G_config.h;hb=cdd45522b6e87369afc341402bda7a95bdf83380) which is the low-level file buffer size itself on opening, not the number of bytes read by `fgetc`. `fgetc` now appears implemented through `int _IO_getc (FILE *fp)` and the use of a `weak alias`. Much easier to track when `stdio/fgetc.c` actually existed (pre 2002).

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe use four ' ' instead of '\t' before ldb, addr, float, stat, j. And the following could work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    char str[100];
    FILE* pointer_file = fopen("test", "r");

    while (fgets(str, sizeof str, pointer_file) != NULL )
        if (str[0] != '\t') {
            fputs(strtok(str, " \t\n"), stdout);
            fputs("\n", stdout );
        }
    fclose(pointer_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like your approach, but recall calling `strtok` on `str` modifies `str` which may prevent its reuse if required. If you wish to remove the leading `'\t'` from `str`, it may be much easier to simply use `str + 1`. Depends on your needs.

Comment: I am sorry, but I think the author means is that if a line is "sta val2", it should ouput "sta" instead of "sta val2" .

Comment: That was unclear to me. That's why I included the description about handling the parsing as needed. Whether by `strtok`, `sscanf` or simply walking a pointer down the string. I'll look again for additional detail, but the thrust seemed to be segregating the the lines beginning with `tab` from the others.

Comment: Updated, used a slightly different parse, but to the same effect.

Comment: I think that you should put your code in a `if` statement that evaluates if the file was correctly open. There could be some reasons for the opening to fail and if you try to `fclose` a pointer that does not point to any file (because it failed to `fopen` it), it will (or may) segfault. Not sure if this is an important detail here though. I'll delete my comment if it is not.

Comment: Thank you very mush for your suggestion. I don't handle these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Either you read entire lines and parse them, or you read characters to drive a Finite State Machine, like:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int ch, state;

for (state =0; ; ) {
        ch = getc(stdin) ;
        if (ch==EOF) break;
        switch(state) {
        case 0: /* initial */
                if (ch == '\t') {state = 2; continue; }
                if (ch == '\n') { continue; }   /* empty line */
                state = 1;
                break;        /* break will emit the character */
        case 1: /* first word on the line */
                if (ch== ' ') {ch = '\n'; state =2; break; }
                if (ch== '\n') {state =0; break; }
                break;
        case 2: /* ignore until EOL */
                if (ch== '\n') {state =0; continue; }
                continue;
                }
        putc(ch, stdout);
        }
return 0;
}
```